# Cron has been running for more than an hour and is most likely stuck

Tags: cron

I am using poorman Cron Run and it is giving error like this: "Cron has been running for more than an hour and is most likely stuck." plz help if any solution for it??

Comment: which version of Drupal are you using?

Comment: i am using drupal 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was because of a second cron `elysia cron` was running with poormans cron. It was fixed. Sorry for not answer it here. I answered it in above comment.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that cron is locked, hence the semaphore variable needs to be deleted before running cron again. In your `includes/common.inc` file, on line 2755 you need to delete the variable from [`drupal_cron_run()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_cron_run/6). You can use the following code:

```
function drupal_cron_run() {
  //The following line will delete the semaphore variable.
  variable_del('cron_semaphore');
  // Try to allocate enough time to run all the hook_cron implementations.
  if (function_exists('set_time_limit')) {
    @set_time_limit(240);
}
```

Then visit `http://yoursite/cron.php` and check the logs for errors.
**Note:** You should comment out the line `variable_del('cron_semaphore');`, after cron runs successfully.
I know it is not recommended to hack the core, but this was the only solution I found useful. If there is any work-around to this solution, please let me know.

Comment: I deleted this variable manually but not works?? :(
hey can we print module name in drupal_cron_run in watchdog function.

Comment: you should clear the cache before running cron again.

Comment: thanks just did the same... lets see if error occurs or not.. because error not occurs when i run the cron mannually but it occurs when cron runs with menu call like wget command..

Comment: this not solved my problem.. :(

Comment: hello hey i just notice i have not cron_semaphore variable it is cron_threshold_semaphore variable.
what should be the reason of this???

Comment: issue fixed.. its because i also enabled a second cron elysia cron with poorman cron..

Comment: ahh.. good for you! all the best. Welcome to Drupal Answers :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you permanently have such errors - it means that you have too much functions that are trying to run during cron.

I advice to install Elysia Cron module http://drupal.org/project/elysia_cron
It will allow you to tune which tasks will run during cron and how often.
This will dramatically increase performance of cron jobs.

Comment: elysia cron was already installed with poorman and i disabled it and my problem solved.. ;) 
heartly thnx for ur attention.. ;)

Comment: Seems you have configured elysia cron in wrong way. Also this module allows you to flush cron semaphore variable easily.

Comment: yaa it can be.. because i was working on site on which it was already installed.. so i dont know how it was configured... :D